# make a dialogflow webhook receiver in django

Tags: django, dialogflow-es

Hi I'm setting up a chatbot using dialogflow, what I want is to integrate dialogflow with django so that a search function in the django server is executed and the result of the research is passed to the chatbot, I made a webhook to the django server in dialogflow using the url "https://0e3c393b.ngrok.io/webhook" but I dont know how make a webhook receiver in django, Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 1):

You should treat it like any other endpoint on django, you will get a request from Dialogflow with a JSON content body, and you will need to reply back with JSON in a specific format. When you want the search behaviour on the chatbot, at that specific intent or flow, have the action be to use a webhook request.

You can find more information here.
https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works